# apache mod_rewrite for autodiscover urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am struggeling with mod_rewrite.

I want to rewrite all URLs of this pattern:

```
[aA][uU][tT][oO][dD][iI][sS][cC][oO][vV][eE][rR].*/UrL/aNy/paTh
```

this maybe

```
auToDiscoveR.example1.com/UrL/aNy/paTh
AUtoDiscoveR.example2.cn/UrL/aNy/paTh
autodiscover.anything.anytld/UrL/aNy/paTh
```

to a URL

```
autodiscover.mydomain.com/url/any/path
```

means I have to replace the DNS/host name and to make the full qualified URL to lowercase. But how to do this in mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to your question is highly dependent on how your virtual hosts are set up. This recipe is correct in the right config.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^autodiscover\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) http://autodiscover.mydomain.com${lc:$1} [R,L]
```

Comment: it is not working.
I do not get the cond. Afaik you are only grabbing fro mydomain.com? How about the other mentioned domains?
I am also not sure, there to place it in a plesk environment, to grab all plesk domains to to redirect to autodiscover.mydomain.com

Comment: I assume this is in a vhost. Do you have a ServerAlias defined for each hostname you are trying to match?

Comment: yes there are bunch of vhosts defined on the apache server. (under plesk 12).  I search for a way to catch all autodiscover.* requests to be redirected to one URL like in the example above

Comment: Hi codnodder, big thx for your help! I have used this for setting up a redirect of all webmail accesses to one specific https-URL. https://der-linux-admin.de/2014/08/plesk-webmail-per-redirect-zu-https-umleiten/ So I assumed also it is possible for any URL. Or do I not get something?